# Sending duplicate data to array, then checking if said array is empty or not to decide what code to run next, if statement not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to include a duplicate check in a script that uses a Google Sheet as an input form for data that sends it to another spreadsheet. I'm trying to set up the check to prevent sending if there are duplicates present or no data, but I keep getting the message saying that there are duplicates even if there are not, or even if there are no values. Any idea on what is going wrong?

Sources of some of my script:
https://techyesplease.com/code/google-apps-script-find-duplicates-sheets/

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/check-if-javascript-array-is-empty-or-not-with-length/

https://amarindaz.com/google-apps-script-if-else-statements/

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ssSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

//These two functions come pretty much copy and pasted from the techyesplease url above, 
// only thing changed was var data to var dataArray as var data was already in use.
function readData() {
  var dataColumn = 3;
  var lastRow = ssSheet.getLastRow();
  var columnRange = sheet.getRange(6, dataColumn, lastRow);
  var rangeArray = columnRange.getValues();
  // Convert to one dimensional array
  rangeArray = [].concat.apply([], rangeArray);
  return rangeArray;
}

// Sort data and find duplicates
function findDuplicates(dataAll) {
  var sortedData = dataAll.slice().sort();
  var duplicates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedData.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sortedData[i + 1] == sortedData[i]) {
      duplicates.push(sortedData[i]);
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}


function sendDataAndTimestamp2() {

//Reference the earlier functions
  var dataArray = readData();
  var duplicates = findDuplicates(dataArray);

//Need to check data and have error message if  duplicates.length >=1, if 0 allow, 
//Also refuse if data length less than 1
  if (duplicates.length !== 0) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Your tallies include duplicates, please remove them then try again.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
/*This above is the only response I get when running the script from the spreadsheet, 
that there are duplicates in the data, even if there are not or there are no values, 
which *should* trigger the next if else instead.*/
Logger.log(duplicates);



  }
  else if (dataArray.length ===0) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You have not input any tallies.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  else {
//    rest of code, unimportant to question as I know it already works.
  
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You're about to notify scheduler of the following number of tallies: " + tallyAmountNumberOnly, SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    //Code to send out emails and data
```

I've tried changing to different ways of checking if the array "duplicates" is empty, like ==null, !=0, >=1, but none of it is working. Is the duplicates array staying full on the next run of the script after the actual duplicate data is deleted from the range? Since it's using getValues I don't think blank cells would be an issue.

Comment: what's the content of sortedData before the loop?

Comment: At the moment, should be nothing, as I have no data in the range it is pulling from. Otherwise it would be a series of four digit numbers.

Comment: could it be that currently has a series of `null` values? That would solve the mistery as null == null is true. Try with console.log(sortedData) before the loop. Also why the `.slice()` in the middle?

Comment: The .slice is just what was in the copy and paste section I got from a guy who had code on finding duplicates here: https://techyesplease.com/code/google-apps-script-find-duplicates-sheets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

It is finding duplicates because you are retrieving several empty cells, and two empty strings are duplicates from each other.

#### Solution:

At `readData`, you are providing `lastRow` as the third parameter of [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows). This refers to the number of rows in your range. Since the first row is 6, the last 6 rows in the retrieved range will be empty cells. You can fix that by making your third parameter `var numRows = lastRow - firstRow + 1` instead.

Also, in order to make sure you have no empty cells in the column, you can remove them from your array via `filter(String)` (see [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)).

Also, I'd suggest using [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) in order to get a 1D array, instead of the more complicated `concat` and `apply` process you're using.

#### Code snippet:

```
function readData() {
  var dataColumn = 3;
  var firstRow = 6;
  var lastRow = ssSheet.getLastRow();
  var numRows = lastRow - firstRow + 1;
  var columnRange = ssSheet.getRange(firstRow, dataColumn, numRows);
  var rangeArray = columnRange.getValues().flat().filter(String);
  return rangeArray;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I see you caught a typo I made where I hadn't changed the variable name for getting the active sheet from "sheet" to "ssSheet" as well. I also have other text on the sheet that means that the data column may not be determining what the last row is if it's less than five cells, so the filter(String) fixes that too.

I admit I really don't know much about concat and apply, I haven't used them yet. Part of the issue in using other people's code when you don't know what it is really doing to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it also be possible to have a cell somewhere that checked `=COUNTA()` vs `=COUNTUNIQUE()` and then your script could simply reference whether the value in that cell was true or false before sending?

Comment: Maybe, but this was what I found for a way to check for duplicates and it works. At this point it's not worth the time to figure out counta and countunique script.