# Google sheets script, Every function combined with && operator and setting range of values to check array against

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Follow up to [Sending duplicate data to array, then checking if said array is empty or not to decide what code to run next, if statement not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177107/sending-duplicate-data-to-array-then-checking-if-said-array-is-empty-or-not-to/67178908#67178908).

I'm pretty much trying to copy the conditional formatting that I put to notify users of "bad" data, but with script to prevent sending bad data and giving unique error messages. With the answer from my last question, the checks and preventing sending no data or data with duplicates works, but I'm now stuck on preventing sending of data that does not match the format of a four digit number.

My conditional formatting was to set the background color to orange on anything that was not equal to or in between 1000 and 9999, but I'm having trouble getting the scripting to work--I'm trying to use negation of anything in  between those two values as the "false" that will prompt an error message, and the "true" to let the rest of the script run that will send the data and notification emails out. However, this makes it say that there are bad values even if I do have the correct data in. Removing the negation lets anything go through, like it's not actually checking it. Any ideas?

The section I'm asking about is the last else if statement:

```
else if (!data.every(function(num) {return num >= 1000 && num <= 9999})) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You have incorrectly formatted tallies, tallies must be four digits.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
```

Total code is below.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ssSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

//https://techyesplease.com/code/google-apps-script-find-duplicates-sheets/
function readData() {
  var dataColumn = 3;
  var firstRow = 6;
  var lastRow = ssSheet.getLastRow();
  var numRows = lastRow - firstRow + 1;
  var columnRange = ssSheet.getRange(firstRow, dataColumn, numRows);
  //var rangeArray = columnRange.getValues();
  // Convert to one dimensional array
  //rangeArray = [].concat.apply([], rangeArray);
  var rangeArray = columnRange.getValues().flat().filter(String);
  return rangeArray;
}

// Sort data and find duplicates
function findDuplicates(dataAll) {
  var sortedData = dataAll.slice().sort();
  var duplicates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedData.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sortedData[i + 1] == sortedData[i]) {
      duplicates.push(sortedData[i]);
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}

//Use the same string for this variable as the name for the requestor for his or her column of data. E.g., John Doe
//****GLOBALS****

var targetSheet = 'All Tallies'; //replace with sheet/tab name
var targetSpreadsheetID = 'id'  //replace with destination ID
var targetURL = 'url'

//var dataNotificationReceivingEmailAddresses = 
//Set up to be able to easily change what emails the data notification goes to?

function sendDataAndTimestamp2() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ssSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var sourceRange = ssSheet.getRange('C6:C401');  
//assign the range you want to copy, could make C6:C? No, would like dynamic.
 var data = sourceRange.getValues();

 var nameRange = ssSheet.getRange('C4:D4');
 var nameValue = nameRange.getDisplayValue();


 var tallyDateRange = ssSheet.getRange('C2');
 var tallyDateValue = tallyDateRange.getDisplayValue();
 var tallyDateText = 'Tallies to run on '+ tallyDateValue;


 var tallyAmountRange = ssSheet.getRange(8,1);
 var tallyAmount = tallyAmountRange.getDisplayValue();
 var tallyAmountNumberOnly = data.filter(String).length; 
//Used as tallyAmount includes text, for some cases need the number only
 
 var thisDocumentUrl = ss.getUrl();
  //Variables for the sending/source spreadsheet above


 //Initial confirmation alert, need checks for blank or error tallies first. First condition needs to loop through data variable and check that if any values are numbers not between 1000 and 9999, throw up Ui alert error message. Second condition goes to result variable?

//Reference the earlier functions
  var dataArray = readData();
  var duplicates = findDuplicates(dataArray);

//Need to check data and have error message if  duplicates.length >=1, if 0 allow, refuse if data length less than 1
  if (duplicates.length !== 0) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Your tallies include duplicates, please remove them then try again.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
Logger.log(duplicates);
  }
  else if (dataArray.length ===0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You have not input any tallies.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }

  else if (!data.every(function(num) {return num >= 1000 && num <= 9999})) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You have incorrectly formatted tallies, tallies must be four digits.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }

/*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaC290XzPX4&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemvD9NFa86_udt-NWh37efmD&index=10
Every method
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var allTalliesGood = data.every(function(num){
    return num < 9
});
//Use with num >= 1000, num <=9999, and then if true continue, if false stop and give error msg
*/




/*
dataFiltered = data.filter(filterlogic);

var filterlogic = function(tally){
  if (tally >= 1000 && tally <= 9999){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false
    }
}
//if use false for good tallies, and rename dataFiltered to something like "dataBad", then check if dataBad has true matches in it...
//need to check for strings? what happens if letters/symbols in tally range?
//var dataBad = data.filter(function(tally){ return tally < 1000 || tally > 9999;});
// use OR (||) for getting tallies great than or less than, what about letters/symbols? Use NOT good range?

//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPCIOohF0Fg&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemvD9NFa86_udt-NWh37efmD&index=8
//sort method link above
*/



  else {
//    rest of code
  


  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You're about to notify scheduler of the following number of tallies: " + tallyAmountNumberOnly, SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);


  if(result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    //Code to send out emails and data
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Are you receiving any errors? Where specifically in your code are you performing the mentioned condition?

Comment: Last else if statement is not working. I already said what my error was.

Comment: And what is the error message? Can you post it here as well? Do you have a mock-up sheet as well?

Comment: "You have incorrectly formatted tallies, tallies must be four digits." Which is my own error message, just it shouldn't be coming up for good values.

Due to work domain restrictions I can't share outside of our network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell in the function `sendDataAndTimestamp2()` you need to get rid of empty values from `data`. It can be done with `filter(String)` method:

```
var data = sourceRange.getValues().filter(String); // <-- here

. . .

else if (!data.every(function(num) {return num >= 1000 && num <= 9999}))

. . .
```

Or, I don't know, perhaps you meant `dataArray` instead of `data`:

```
else if (!dataArray.every(function(num) {return num >= 1000 && num <= 9999}))
```

Btw, the line can be shortened a bit:

```
else if (!data.every(x => (x >= 1000) && (x <= 9999)))
```

Comment: I'm not actually trying to get rid of them, I'm trying to force the user to make the data values correct before they can send them, so we don't get an issue of "why wasn't my tally run" because it was incorrect and then have to deal with finding what the incorrect one was.

Comment: Ah, ok, so filter(String) won't mess with the comparison operation, I was assuming that I needed to keep them in number format. So the getValues is picking up empty cells within the range and those all are less than 1000 so they trip the else if. Thanks!

Comment: If you want keep the empty cells (and get error message in this case) you can apply `.flat()` instead of `filter(String)`. This way you will get 1-dimensional array instead 2-dimensional. If you need 2-dimensional array you can apply flat method only in the line "else if": `else if (!data.flat().every(x => (x >= 1000) && (x <= 9999)))`